# Java - Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: java, user-interface

I am creating simple game in java. Here is my code. This is my GUI class:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

JButton upbutton, downbutton, leftbutton, rightbutton;

Game game;
Player player;
Board b;
Maze maze;
Player pl;

public GUI () {
    b= new Board();
    Game game = new Game(b);


    setSize(800,600);
    Container cp = getContentPane();

    upbutton = new JButton("UP");
    downbutton = new JButton("DOWN");   
    leftbutton = new JButton("LEFT");
    rightbutton= new JButton("RIGHT");
    upbutton.addActionListener(this);
    downbutton.addActionListener(this);
    leftbutton.addActionListener(this);
    rightbutton.addActionListener(this);

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    BoxLayout boxLayout1 = new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(250, 0, 250, 0));
    p.setLayout(boxLayout1);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    p.add(panel_1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
    p.add(panel_2);

    JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
    p.add(panel_3, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);

    panel_1.add(upbutton);
    panel_2.add(leftbutton);
    panel_2.add(rightbutton);
    panel_3.add(downbutton);

    cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    cp.add(p, BorderLayout.EAST);

    game= new Game(b);
    cp.add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(upbutton == e.getSource()){
        game.movePlayerUp();
        System.out.println("up");
        }
    if(downbutton == e.getSource()){
        game.movePlayerDown();
        System.out.println("down");
        repaint();
        }
    if(leftbutton == e.getSource()){
        game.movePlayerLeft();
        repaint();
        System.out.println("left");
        }
    if(rightbutton == e.getSource()){
        game.movePlayerRight();
        repaint();
        System.out.println("right");
        }
    game.repaint();
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUI frame = new GUI();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

This is my Game class:

public class Game extends Canvas {

```
int m;
int n;  // the margin
Board b;
double tokenSize, markingSize;
int[][] marking;
int pickupType;
int pickupX, pickupY;
Dimension lastSize;
Image picture;
Maze maze;
Player player;

boolean ingame = false; 
boolean dying = false; 
boolean finished = false;
Thread gamethread = null;

int pposition [][];
public int positiona;
public int positionb;

public final Font smallfont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14);

public Game (Board db) {
    pposition = new int[4][4];
    maze = new Maze();
    b=db;
    m=20;
    setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    lastSize=getSize();
    picture=createImage(lastSize.width, lastSize.height);
    createPlayerBoard();
    setInitialPlayerPosition();
}

public void paint (Graphics g){
    update(g);
}

public synchronized void update(Graphics g1) {

    Dimension d=getSize();
    if (!d.equals(lastSize)) {
        picture=createImage(d.width, d.height);
    } 

    Graphics g=picture.getGraphics();

    g.setColor(getBackground());
    g.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
    g.setColor(getForeground());
    g.drawRect(0, 0, d.width-1, d.height-1);
    int h=getHeight();
    int w=getWidth();

    int squareSize = Math.max(0,(Math.min(h,w)-2*m))/8;
    squareSize = squareSize+40;

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Image img1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("3down.jpg");
    Image img2 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("3left.jpg");
    Image img3 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("3right.jpg");
    Image img4 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("3up.jpg");
    Image img5 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("all4.jpg");
    Image img6 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("down_left.jpg");
    Image img7 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("down_right.jpg");
    Image img8 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("up_left.jpg");
    Image img9 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("up_right.jpg");
    Image img10 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("cyclops.gif");

    //this code displays board

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<5; j++) {
            if(i==0&&j==0){
            g2.drawImage(img7,m + i * squareSize, m + j * squareSize, squareSize, squareSize, this);
            g2.finalize();}
            else if(i==1&&j==0){
            g2.drawImage(img1,m + i * squareSize, m + j * squareSize, squareSize, squareSize, this);
            g2.finalize();}
            else if (i==2&&j==0){
            g2.drawImage(img1,m + i * squareSize, m + j * squareSize, squareSize, squareSize, this);
            g2.finalize();}
            else if (i==3&&j==0){
            g2.drawImage(img1,m + i * squareSize, m + j * squareSize, squareSize, squareSize, this);
            g2.finalize();}
            else if (i==4 &&j==0){
            g2.drawImage(img6,m + i * squareSize, m + j * squareSize, squareSize, squareSize, this);
            g2.finalize();}
    }

    //this code will display the cyclop

    loadPlayerPosition();
    int x=positiona;
    int y=positionb;

    g2.drawImage(img10,m + x * squareSize, m + y * squareSize, squareSize, squareSize, this);
    g2.finalize();

g1.drawImage(picture,0,0,null);
}
    //this method creates player board and fills all places in array with 0
public void createPlayerBoard(){
    for (int i = 0; i < pposition.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < pposition.length; j++){
                pposition[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

//this method sets the initial player position in array
public void setInitialPlayerPosition(){
    pposition[0][0] = 1;

}

//this method changes the interger positiona and positib be, so integers represent the current player position
public void loadPlayerPosition(){
    for (int i = 0; i < pposition.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < pposition.length; j++){
            if(pposition [i][j] == 1){
                positiona=i;
                positionb=j;
                    }
        }
    }
}

//these methods change the number in player array from 0 to 1, deppending on which button player clicked

public void movePlayerUp(){
    for (int i = 0; i < pposition.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < pposition.length; j++){
            if(pposition [i][j] == 1){
                pposition [i][j] = 0;
                pposition [i][j+1] = 1;
                    }
        }
    }
}

public void movePlayerDown(){
    for (int i = 0; i < pposition.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < pposition.length; j++){
            if(pposition [i][j] == 1){
                pposition [i][j] = 0;
                pposition [i][j-1] = 1;
                    }
        }
    }
}

public void movePlayerLeft(){
    for (int i = 0; i < pposition.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < pposition.length; j++){
            if(pposition [i][j] == 1){
                pposition [i][j] = 0;
                pposition [i-1][j] = 1;
                    }
        }
    }
}

public void movePlayerRight(){
    for (int i = 0; i < pposition.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < pposition.length; j++){
            if(pposition [i][j] == 1){
                pposition [i][j] = 0;
                pposition [i+1][j] = 1;
                    }
        }
    }
}
```

}
This is my board class:

public class Board {

```
int[][] b;
Maze maze;
boolean alive = true;
public int playerscore = 0;
Maze m;



public Board() {

    }
```

}

The program normally creates the windows with buttons, displays the board and displays the player icon. What I want to do is:
when player clicks on right button, the icon moves right on the array. When I click on the button, I get this error:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

I try to search the error and it says this happens when the program points to object which is null.However, I think my object is not null. Can somebody give me advice please? Thank you very much

Comment: Can you please post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Yes, please post the stacktrace or at least identify the row that is causing the exception.

Comment: Also, unrelated, but why do you have `game = new Game(b)` twice in your gui constructor?